# Feature for viewing unanswered questions only under selected tags

Tags: feature-request

I couldn't find any option that would help one to see the unanswered questions under selected tags.

Say I want to see all questions tagged with PHP that haven't been answered yet. How would I do that?

I'm fairly new to this place. Am I missing something or does Stack Overflow not have a feature like that?

Comment: i can see it ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: SO]

See the "unanswered" tab on top right of the image. Every tag has its own "unanswered " questions tab

Comment: thanks. +1 for the screenshot. I wonder how i missed something right under my nose! :) My bad.

Comment: it happens.. :)

Answer (score 3):

Click on the ["unanswered" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=unanswered&pagesize=30) while browsing [questions tagged [php]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), or, alternatively, [search for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bphp%5D%20answers:0%20closed:0) `[php] answers:0 closed:0`.

Comment: Thanks @Yannis. That worked like a charm. But i was wondering, wouldnt it be much easier if i could select one tag coupled with unanswered button bringing up all the unanswered questions under that tag? Just a thought!

Comment: Just click on the tag, it will take you to the tag's page, where you'll have the same tabs available as in the homepage (newest, featured, faq, votes, active, unanswered), but only for the tag's questions. All tag pages follow this url schema: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag>`

Comment: @Orbb Check the screenshot in my answer.

Comment: fantastic stuff!!! You had posted, What I exactly wanted... I am lazy to search but active on posting stuff...this time I wasn't lazy to search and I got it. Most of the time I don't get what I wanted here on stack exchange after hours of search. This time it's a minutes of search and got it. But my doubt is is that really pulling up only questions with PHP tag? or it's just a another kind of filter...